# RestEasy client can't use @PathParam arguments

Tags: java, resteasy

Hy, I have a problem using resteasy client method with a PathParam. I explain :

I have an interface used on client side and server side :

```java
@Path("/1.0/user")
@Consumes({"application/json"})
@Produces({"application/json"})
public interface UserApi {
  @GET
  @Path("/{userid}/followers")
  @PrivateApi
  public List<DXUser> getUserFollowers(@PathParam("userid") long userId);
}
```

On the server side, this worked as expected, I have a concrete class implementing this interface and my API is online. No problem. I can call this API method from the URL: http://myapi.dev/1.0/user/1234/followers

But, on the client side, I use the interface to call the API easily with the following code :

```java
ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target("http://myapi.dev");
UserApi api = target.proxy(UserApi.class);
List<DXUser> users = api.getUserFollowers(1234);
```

And I receive an exception : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You did not supply enough values to fill path parameters

I try with @POST in place of @GET method. I have the same error.
I try with @QueryParam and it works ! So the problem seams to concern only @PathParam.

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong in this case.
Do you have any idea how can I fix that ?

Thank you
Seb

Comment: When I try that, I got the following exception : RuntimeException: You must define a @Consumes type on your client method or interface, or supply a default when I call target.proxy(UserApi.class)...

Comment: can't you debug your client code to actually see why the exception is thrown?

Comment: I have debugged it and the problem seems to occur in RestEasyUriBuilder.buildFromValues method. This method is called with no values, It find it should have one parameter ("userid") so it throws the exception. The question is why it couldn't found the value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, I made a mistake.

I have imported the **javax.websocket.server.PathParam** annotation in place of the **javax.ws.rs.PathParam**.

So, the Resteasy ClientProxy could not create the good PathParamProcessor.

Sorry for this mistake.